# Arch Linux - Cronie is not working and nestat does not output logs?

Tags: arch-linux, syslog, netstat, lsof, r

I added a cronjob via crontab -e which is to be executed every minute. I enabled and started cronie on systemctl.

## Set editor

```
$ export EDITOR=vim
```

## Add cront tasks

```
$ crontab -e

* * * * * Rscript /srv/shiny-system/cron/CPU.R
~
~
"/tmp/crontab.8VZ7vq" 1 line, 47 characters
```

## Install cronie

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu cronie
$ sudo systemctl enable --now cronie.service
$ systemctl status cronie
```

## List cron tasks

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * Rscript /srv/shiny-system/cron/CPU.R
```

I wrote this program below in R, when I start it in the shell it workes fine, but when i start it with cronie it just doesn't do what it is supposed to do.

```
setwd("/srv/shiny-system/cron")
I <- 0
for (i in 1:60) {
    system("top -n 1 -b -u shiny > top.log")
    dat <- readLines("top.log")
    id <- grep("R$", dat)

    Names <- strsplit(gsub("^ +|%|\\+", "", dat[7]), " +")[[1]]

    if (length(id) > 0) {
        # ‘top’ data frame;
        L <- strsplit(gsub("^ *", "", dat[id]), " +")
        dat <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(L), ncol = 12, byrow = T))
        names(dat) <- Names
        dat <- data.frame(Time = Sys.time(), dat[, -ncol(dat)], usr = NA, app = NA)
        dat$CPU <-as.numeric(as.character(dat$CPU))
        dat$MEM <-as.numeric(as.character(dat$MEM))

        # Check if connection number changed;
        for (i in 1:length(dat$PID)) {
            PID <- dat$PID[i]
            system(paste("sudo -i netstat -p | grep ", PID, " > netstat.log"))
            # system(paste("sudo -i netstat -p | grep ", PID, " >> netstat.log2"))
            system(paste("sudo -i lsof -p ", PID, " | grep DIR > lsof.log"))
            netstat <- readLines("netstat.log")
            lsof <- readLines("lsof.log")
            dat$usr[i] <- length(grep("ESTABLISHED", netstat) & grep("tcp", netstat))

            dat$app[i] <- regmatches(lsof, regexec("srv/shiny-server/(.*)", lsof))[[1]][2]

        }
        dat <- dat[, c("app", "usr")]
    } else {
        dat <- data.frame(app = "app1", usr = 0)
    }
    write.table(dat, file = "CPU.txt")
}
```

This program generates these 4 files below and cronie **seems** to be running bcos I can see them in this location /srv/shiny-system/cron,

```
top.log
netstat.log
lsof.log
CPU.txt
```

But the problem is there is no log/ data/ info in `netstat.log` and `lsof.log`

So is this a problem in my R program or in cronie actually?

But when I run this program with the cron in **Ubuntu Linux**, I get the data I am after in `netstat.log` and `lsof.log`.

So is this a bug/ problem in Arch Linux?? It seems that Arch has a problem with `netstat` and `lsof`. I have `netstat` installed as well,

## Install net-tools for netstat

```
$ sudo pacman -S net-tools
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `top.log` contain the right data? have ou tried deleting it and then seeing if it is created again? I just wan to make 100% sure that the crontab is actually being run and is correctly executing the R script. By the way, kudos for using R of all things for something like that. You could simplify it enormously to just a few lines of bash; ask a question explaining what you are logging if you're interested.

Comment: `Does the top.log contain the right data?` Yes it does.

Comment: `have ou tried deleting it and then seeing if it is created again?` Yes I have

Comment: hang on, how are you passing the password to sudo? And why are you using -i?

Comment: `how are you passing the password to sudo?` good question! I did not pass the password to sudo becos I dunno how that's why I am using `-i`. Is it becos of the password so netstat.log and lsof.log are empty?

Comment: probably, yes. The command won't run without a password. Try adding it to root's crontab instead and removing the sudo..

Comment: `Try adding it to root's crontab instead` - how? what is the command for root's crontab? I thought `crontab -e` is adding to the root's.

Comment: no, crontab -e will add it to whichever user's is running the command. You can get root's with `sudo crontab - e`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36074/discussion-between-terdon-and-teelou).